# Is flutter test file important?

Tags: flutter

flutter object has file called "test" who including "widget_test.dart" when I delete this file nothing happens to my app and still working 
is this file important to my project or I should delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a file for putting your [unit tests](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction) in.  It's not necessary for your code to run, but you'll become a much better developer and write much better code if you incorporate unit testing into your workflow.